# How to properly resolve and use promise.all()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to use window.fetch and promises to build an ajax pattern where I have:

1. Controllers that initiate the calls
2. Services that define the urls and parameters necessary for the app
3. Utilities to provide generic functions for fetching

I can't seem to get the dataflow to fall through all the functions quite right so I think that I must have something hooked up wrong. I think it is probably in the Promise.all() because the `.then()` in the utilities is firing before the call has actually completed so the `response` is blank.

My code is below (and there is a gist as well). I haven't used promises much before so I may be coming at this all wrongy...

controller.js

```
import {fetchHistoryData} from '/service'

function initChart(config = this.defaultConfig){
    fetchHistoryData()
        .then((response)=> {
            buildChart();
        }).catch(()=>{
        console.error('Could not get data.');
    });
}
}
```

fetchutils.js

```
function fetchData(url, options = {mode: 'cors'}, formatter = ((data)=>data)){
    console.log(url);
    return window.fetch(url, options)
        .then(status)
        .then(formatter)
        .then(function(data){
            return data;
        })
        .catch(throwError);
}
```

service.js

```
import {fetchData} from './fetchUtils'

export function fetchHistoryData(){
    return Promise.all([fetchHistory('set1'), fetchHistory('set2')]);
        //.then((result)=>result); ??
}

function fetchHistory(name){
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        const url = createHistoryUrl(name);
        resolve (fetchData(url, {mode:'no-cors'}, historyFormatter));
    });
}
```

https://gist.github.com/thedamon/86601ba009bfd05cb791

Comment: Looking over it quickly, it looks like all the `then` 's are in the right places and should work as expected. The three `then` 's chained to the returned promise from the `fetch` will finally return the data, and `fetchHistoryData` should return an array of that data etc.

Answer (score 1):

there are few issues with this code,

- `initChart` function is not returning anything,
- you are wrapping promises with promises in `fetchHistory`, not sure why
- in case you are wondering, `Promise.all` would return an array of results( i.e one result per promise)
- I can understand the default `formatter` method, but next operation in the then chain does nothing in `fetchData`,

effectively your code can be reduced to:

```
//controller.js

import {fetchHistoryData} from '/service'

function initChart(config = this.defaultConfig){
  return fetchHistoryData()
    .then(response=> buildChart())
    .catch(()=>  console.error('Could not get data.'));
}

//fetchutils.js

function fetchData(url, options = {mode: 'cors'}, formatter = data => data ){
  console.log(url);
  return window.fetch(url, options)
    .then(status)
    .then(formatter)
    .catch(throwError); // not sure if catch is need here
}

//service.js 

import {fetchData} from './fetchUtils'

export function fetchHistoryData(){
  return Promise.all(['set1', 'set2'].map(fetchHistory));
    //.then((result)=>result); ??
}

function fetchHistory(name){
  return fetchData(createHistoryUrl(name), {mode:'no-cors'}, historyFormatter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! re your comments: (1) initChart was just mucking with the DOM so no need to return I thought. (2) yehh i dno what's up with that. simplification good! (4) i thought an explicit `return` statement was necessary at some point.. it is not?   I will put in as changed and see if i'm still having issues. again, thank you!

Comment: It looks as though just `window.fetch` in `fetchData` is jumping the gun and running its first then before the fetch is complete... (it logs logs from the `.then`s off the fetch before the `fetch complete`